# Microsoft Graph API - Get Message - Recipient alias

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We want to have an application that uses an API (Graph Office365 REST) to go through emails messages and lists the recipient email aliases. Our email user has couple of aliases through which we can receive email into the same inbox.

for example - primaryEmail@my-company.com (primary email)
aliases - primaryEmail.alias1@my-company.com (alias 1) and primaryEmail.alias2@my-company.com (alias 2)

when we send emails to primaryEmail.alias1@my-company.com the email is received correctly against primaryEmail@example.com inbox. When I use the API (me/messages/{ID} or me/messages/{ID}?$select=internetMessageHeaders) to list the properties of the email Alias propterty is missing and the ToRecipients property is already resolved to primaryEmail@my-company.com.

Is there a way to enable the toRecipient email Alias property in the Message object. Please help...

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I need this too.